# How do I get rid of this TypeError for an index that is obviously an integer?

Tags: python, cs50

I am trying to make a program that prints out whether a particular string is a valid license plate or not based on these rules:

> All vanity plates must start with at least two letters.
>
> … vanity plates may contain a maximum of 6 characters (letters or
> numbers) and a minimum of 2 characters.
>
> Numbers cannot be used in the middle of a plate; they must come at
> the end. For example, AAA222 would be an acceptable … vanity plate;
> AAA22A would not be acceptable. The first number used cannot be a
> ‘0’.
>
> No periods, spaces, or punctuation marks are allowed.

Code is below:

```
def main():

    plate = input("Plate: ")
    if is_valid(plate):
        print("Valid")
    else:
        print("Invalid")

def is_valid(s):

    if s[0].isdigit() or s[1].isdigit():
        return 0
    if s.isalnum() == 0:
        return 0
    if len(s) < 2 or len(s) > 6:
        return 0
    for i in s:
        if s.find("0") != -1:
            if s[i].isdigit():
                if s.find("0") <= i:
                    return 0
                if s[i+1].isalpha():
                    return 0
    return 1

main()
```

When I enter in CS50 as an input, I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/workspaces/73610102/plates/plates.py", line 23, in <module>
main()
File "/workspaces/73610102/plates/plates.py", line 3, in main
if is_valid(plate):
File "/workspaces/73610102/plates/plates.py", line 17, in is_valid
if s[i].isdigit():
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

The error message seems to be telling me that i in s[i] is not an integer, even though 'i' is being iterated over in a loop in the string s... I tried putting i = 0 in the line before the loop, but the error wasn't fixed when I did that. What else can I do?

Comment: `i` is not an index, it is a character from the string you're iterating over.

Comment: Where is `s` even defined?

Comment: @nordmanden s is the parameter of function `is_valid(s)`, which is entered by the user in function `main()` as the variable `plate`.  The incorrect indentation/formatting of the code example makes it unclear.

Comment: `s[i].isdigit()` should be `i.isdigit()`

Comment: Or change `for i in s:` to `for i in range(len(s))`:

Comment: Why are you testing `s.find("0")` inside the loop? It has nothing to do with the current iteration of the loop.

Comment: @nigh_anxiety That's a possibility, but it's more pythonic to use `for i in s:`

Comment: `i` implies index, `c` as in 'char' would be better

Comment: Is there any reason to return `0` and `1` instead of `True` and `False`?

Comment: @josh-stackoverflow: No, it would be better with bools. Similarly, in `if s.isalnum() == 0:`, `isalnum` actually returns a bool not an int, but they work for truth checks. Nevertheless, the check isn't even required. `if s.isalnum():` is sufficient.

Answer (score -1):

Please check below code

```
def isValid_plate(s):
    first_char = []
    while True:
        if len(s) > 0 and s[0].isalpha():
            first_char.append(s[0])
            s = s[1:]
        else:
            break
    
    if len(first_char) < 2:
        return False
    elif len(s) == 0:
        return True
    
    
    if all(c.isdigit() for c in s) and s[0] != '0':
        return True
    else:
        return False


status = {0: "Invalid", 1: "Valid"}

print(f"Plate number AAA222 is {status[isValid_plate('AAA222')]}")
print(f"Plate number AAA22A is {status[isValid_plate('AAA22A')]}")
print(f"Plate number A9AA222 is {status[isValid_plate('A9AA222')]}")
print(f"Plate number ABV022 is {status[isValid_plate('ABV022')]}")
print(f"Plate number ZKY is {status[isValid_plate('ZKY')]}")

Plate number AAA222 is Valid
Plate number AAA22A is Invalid
Plate number A9AA222 is Invalid
Plate number ABV022 is Invalid
Plate number ZKY is Valid
```