# CS50 vanity plates detecting numbers amid letters

Tags: python, cs50

I write a code to verify the license plates of cars and there are some conditions to achieve this purpose:

- The first number should not be `0`
- It shouldn't have any numbers between letters(`AAA12` is ok, but `AA2AAA` is not.)
- It should start with two letters
- The count of characters must be between 2 - 6 letters
- Only letters and numbers allowed

```py
def is_valid(s):
    s = s.lower()
    if len(s) >= 2 and len(s) <= 6 and s[0] != 0 and s[0:2].isalpha():
        if s.isalpha():
            return True
        elif s.isalnum():
            for sq in s.split():
                for w in sq:
                    if w.isdigit():
                        x = sq.index(w)
                        try:
                            if s[w:].isalpha():
                                return False
                            else:
                                return True
    
                        except:
                            return True
```

So my code is doing most of these conditions in a right way, but when I enter e.g. `HL23P2`, I expect to get `False` but it returns `True`.

Why does it return `False`? because I can't have numbers between letters only it is allowed when its like e.g. `HEL23`.

But how can I detect numbers between letters?

Comment: I can't help but thing that regex would be the way to solve this.

Comment: Agree about regex but if you really needed no regex:  put in some sample datas along with expected outputs.  Right I am not sure how returning a boolean relates to your title, so can’t reason well about your code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73379734/how-do-i-get-rid-of-this-typeerror-for-an-index-that-is-obviously-an-integer is this answer your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CS50P PSETS 2, Vanity plates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73648306/cs50p-psets-2-vanity-plates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this solution without regular expression would be ok:

```
def is_valid(s):
    meetNumber = False
    if len(s) >= 2 and len(s) <= 6 and s[0:2].isalpha():
        for i in range(2, len(s)):
            if s[i].isnumeric():
                meetNumber = True
            elif meetNumber == True:
                return False
        return True
    else:
        return False

print(is_valid(input()))
```

Comment: this answer is wrong and fails to fail on a leading 0

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
import re

def is_valid(s):
    return bool(re.search(r'^(?=.{2,6}$)[A-Z]{2,}\d*$', s))

print([is_valid(el) for el in ['AAA12', 'AA2AAA', 'HL23P2', 'HEL23']])
```

Prints:

```
[True, False, False, True]
```

---

The regular expression used means:

- `^` - Start string;
- `(?=.{2,6}$)` - Positive lookahead to match 2-6 characters exactly untill end-string anchor (accomodate your requirement of 2-6 characters total);
- `[A-Z]{2,}` - 2+ uppercase alpha (accomodate your requirement to start with at least 2 alphachars);
- `\d*` - 0+ digits (accomodate your requirement to have no numbers between characters but only possible at end);
- `$` - End-string anchor.

Comment: `is_valid("0ASDSD")` returns `True` although from what I understand it should return `False` because question states "No 0 at the first letter"

Comment: @g14u, it returns `False` to me to be honest, as it should.

Comment: sorry my fault. It returns `False` to me now as well.

Comment: this doesnt seem to accommodate the rule that 0 can't be the first digit used but is otherwise quite good looking. you could easily fix that by using a [1-9]*[0-9]* at the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_valid(s):
    if 2 <= len(s) <= 6 and s[0:2].isalpha() and s.isalnum():
        for item in s:
            if item.isdigit():
                pos = s.index(item)
                if s[pos:].isdigit() and int(item) != 0:
                    return True
                else:
                    return False

        return True
```