# CS50P PSETS 2, Vanity plates

Tags: python, cs50

I'm having some issues with the psets2 of cs50p, precisely I'm talking about the "Vanity Plates" problem, where I fulfilled all requests except one, which said:

“Numbers cannot be used in the middle of a plate; they must come at the end. For example, AAA222 would be an acceptable … vanity plate; AAA22A would not be acceptable. The first number used cannot be a ‘0’.” Can you help me?

To be clear the full requirements are: (more info found [here](https://cs50.harvard.edu/python/2022/psets/2/plates/))

> “All vanity plates must start with at least two letters.”
> “… vanity plates may contain a maximum of 6 characters (letters or numbers) and a minimum of 2 characters.”
> “Numbers cannot be used in the middle of a plate; they must come at the end. For example, AAA222 would be an acceptable … vanity plate; AAA22A would not be acceptable. The first number used cannot be a ‘0’.”
> “No periods, spaces, or punctuation marks are allowed.”

this is the code I wrote so far:

```
def main():
    plate = input("Plate: ")
    if is_valid(plate):
    print("Valid")
    else:
    print("Invalid")

    def is_valid(s):
        if s.isalnum() || s[:2].isalpha() || 2 < len(s) < 6 :
           return True
        else:
           return False

main()
```

Comment: You should put a clear and complete *Problem description* here, and don't assume people will know all the requirements.  Also, please fix the *indentation*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect numbers between letters in a string python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73428241/detect-numbers-between-letters-in-a-string-python)

Answer (score 2):

This is how I did it. I am sure there is an easier way to do it out there but hopefully this helps :)

```
characters = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']
numbers = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0']

def main ():
plate = (input ("Plate: ")).upper()
if is_valid(plate):
    print ('Valid')
else:
    print ('Invalid')

def is_valid (s):
#Check whether length is between 2 and 6 included
if len(s) < 2 or len(s) > 6:
    return False
elif char_check(s):
    return False
elif char_start(s):
    return False
elif zero_check(s):
    return False
elif alpha_follow_check (s):
    return False
else:
    return True
#Check for valid characters
def char_check(s):
  for i in s:
    if not (i in characters or i in numbers):
        return True

#Check whether first two are letters
 def char_start (s):
  for i in s[:2]:
    if not i in characters:
        return True

#Check if zero is first number listed
def zero_check (plate_response):
 length_string = len (plate_response)
 letter_position = 0
 number_present = 0
 zero_position = None
 if any (i in numbers for i in plate_response):
    for i in plate_response [0:length_string]:
        if i == '0':
            zero_position = letter_position
            break
        letter_position = letter_position + 1
    for i in plate_response [0:zero_position]:
        if i in numbers:
            number_present = 1
    if number_present == 0:
        return True
  else:
    return False

#Check alphabet follows numbers
 def alpha_follow_check (plate_response):
   length_string = len (plate_response)
   letter_position = 0
   number_position = None
   if any (i in numbers for i in plate_response):
     for i in plate_response [0:length_string]:
        if i in numbers:
            number_position = letter_position
            break
        letter_position = letter_position + 1
     for i in plate_response [number_position:length_string]:
        if i in characters:
            return True
   else:
    return False

   main ()
```

Answer (score 2):

This should help, I have tested it with all conditions and is working for me!

```
def main():
    plate = input("Plate: ")
    if is_valid(plate):
        print("Valid")
    else:
        print("Invalid")

def is_valid(s):
    digits = 0

    valid = False
    while not valid:
        # minimum 2 and max 6 charcters(numbers and letters)
        if 2 <= len(s) <= 6 and s.isalnum():
            # if only 2 charcater then should only be letters
            if len(s) == 2 and not s.isalpha():
                valid = False
                break
            else:
                for i in s:
                    #if plate have digits value of digits variable gets updated accordingly
                    if i.isdigit():
                        digits += 1

                # checking condition one by one from character ranging 2 to 6
                if digits == 0 and len(s) >= 2:
                    valid = True
                    break

                if digits == 1 and s[-1].isdigit() and s[-1] != '0':
                    print(digits)
                    valid = True
                    break

                if digits == 2 and s[-2:].isdigit() and s[-2] != '0':
                    valid = True
                    break

                if digits == 3 and s[-3:].isdigit() and s[-3] != '0':
                    valid = True
                    break

                if digits == 4 and s[-4:] and s[-4] != '0':
                    valid = True
                    break

                else:
                    valid = False
                    break
                    
        else:
            valid = False
            break

    return valid


main()
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to consider all the cases one by one, this is how I solved it:

```
def main():
    plate = input("Plate: ")
    if is_valid(plate):
        print("Valid")
    else:
        print("Invalid")


def is_valid(s):
    if  len(s) < 2 or len(s) > 6:
        return False
    elif not s[0].isalpha() or not s[1].isalpha():
        return False
    elif checkFirstZero(s):
        return False
    elif checkMiddleZero(s):
        return False
    elif last(s):
        return False
    elif worng(s):
        return False
    return True

def last(s):
    isAlp = False
    isNum = False
    for w in s:
        if not w.isalpha():
            isNum = True
        else:
            if isNum:
                return True
    return False

def checkCuntuNNumber(s):
    isFirstTry = True
    isNum = False
    for w in s:
        if not w.isalpha():
            if isFirstTry:
                isNum = True
                isFirstTry = False
    if isNum and s[-1].isalpha():
        return True


def checkMiddleZero(s):
    isFirstTry = True
    isNum = False
    for w in s:
        if not w.isalpha():
            if isFirstTry:
                isNum = True
                isFirstTry = False
    if isNum and s[-1].isalpha():
        return True
    else:
        return False

def checkFirstZero(s):
    for w in s:
        if not w.isalpha():
            if int(w) == 0:
                return True
            else:
                return False

def worng(s):
    for w in s:
        if w in [" ", ".", ","]:
            return True
    return False


main()
```

Comment: thank you very much, I'll try to understand the code and rewrite it my way

Comment: what is checkCuntUNNumber used by

Answer (score 1):

idk if will help, but the part that i've had the most difficulty in this problem was: "*Numbers cannot be used in the middle of a plate; they must come at the end, AAA22A would not be acceptable*", then i learned that you can create a full list from the plate that the user inputed, and how to actually use it, with the:

```
ls = list(s)  
    for i in range(len(ls)):
```

After that, we check when the first number appears. "`if == '0'`" ,then returns False to the function.
After that, if the first number isn't a 0, the program checks if the next item in that list is letter, and, if it is, also return False.
`i < len(ls) -1` => this part guarantee that the program will not run in the last item of the list
`ls[i+1].isalpha()` => and this part check that, if the item on the list was a number, and then the next item is a letter, it returns False
I hope it helps someone, i've spend a lot of time trying to figure it out what to do, and then reached this solution: "`for i in range(len(ls))`".
Now my code is complete and working.
My code:

```
def main():
    plate = input("Plate: ")
    if is_valid(plate):
        print("Valid")
    else:
        print("Invalid")
def is_valid(s):
    if not s.isalnum():
        return False
    elif len(s) < 4 or len(s) > 7:
        return False
    elif s[0].isdigit()or s[1].isdigit():
        return False
    elif s[-1].isalpha() or s[-2].isalpha():
        return False 
    else:
        ls = list(s)  
        for i in range(len(ls)):
            if ls[i].isdigit():
                if ls[i] == '0':
                    return False
                elif i < len(ls) -1 and ls[i+1].isalpha():
                    return False
                else:
                    return True
main()
```

Comment: creating a list from the string has no value.  you can access the individual characters already using the exact syntax you used becuase the value is a string.  just use len(s) no need for ls at all.

Comment: why are you checking for 4 and 7 as bounds. it can be two characters..  also your check on the first two characters doesnt fail if they use symbols.  use not isalpha  instead of isdigit.
why cant the last two characters be alphas?  all alpha is allowed.
your solution is wrong

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it.

```py
def main():
    plate = input("Plate: ")
    if is_valid(plate):
        print("Valid")
    else:
        print("Invalid")


def is_valid(s):
    if 1 < len(s) <= 6 and s[:2].isalpha() and s.isalnum():
        divide = [s[:len(s)//2], s[len(s)//2:]]
        if divide[1][0] == '0':
            return False
        else:
            return True

main()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: your answer also contains invalid syntax and is wildly incorrect

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
def main():
    plate = input("Plate: ")
    if is_valid(plate):
        print("Valid")
    else:
        print("Invalid")


def is_valid(s):
    if check_length(s) and check_begin(s) and check_spec(s) and check_numbers(s):
        return True
    else:
        return False


def check_length(s):
    if not 2<= len(s) <= 6:
        return False
    else:
        return True

def check_begin(s):
    for c in s[:2]:
        if c.isdigit():
            return False
    return True


def check_spec(s):
    for c in s:
        if not c.isalpha() and not c.isdigit():
            return False
    return True

def check_numbers(s):
    firstnum = None
    for c in s:
        if c.isdigit():
            firstnum = c
            break
    if firstnum == None:
        return True
    if int(firstnum) == 0:
        return False
    index = s.index(firstnum)
    position = len(s) - index
    for c in s[-position:]:
        if not c.isdigit():
            return False
    return True


main()
```

For me it was easier to manage each condition as separate functions and the required is_valid() function checks the validity through these "subfunctions".

Answer (score 1):

Still learning but that's how i solved it

```
def main():
    plate = input("Plate: ").upper()
    if is_valid(plate):
        print("Valid")
    else:
        print("Invalid")


def is_valid(s):

    if s.isalnum()==False:  
        return False

    elif len(s)<2 or len(s)>6:
        return False
    L=list(s)

    if L[0].isdigit or not L[1].isdigit:
        return False

    for i in L[0:(len(L)-1)]:
        k=L.index(i)
        if i.isdigit()==False:
            if L[k+1]=='0':
                return False
        elif i.isdigit()==True:
            if L[k+1].isdigit()==False:
                return False
    else:
        return True
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: your answer is flat out wrong sorry. please look harder and try more attempts and examples.   you dont need to use a list either, iterator over a counter for the digits of the string.   also 011111 will pass.

Answer (score 1):

```
import string

def main():
    plate = input("Plate: ").lower()
    if is_valid(plate):
        print("Valid")
    else:
        print("Invalid")


def is_valid(n):
    # if all the user-defined functions returns 'True' then the if-else block returns 'True'
    if length_checker(n) and beginning_letter_check(n) and sign_checker(n) and middle_number_checker(n) and zero_checker(n):
        return True
    # if any one of the user-defined functions returns 'False' then the if-else block returns 'False'
    else:
        return False

# function to checks the length of the plate number inputted as it should be between 2 and 6 inclusive
def length_checker(l):
    if (2 <= len(l) <= 6):
        return True
    else:
        return False

# function to check that the beginning of the plate numbers should be alphabets and not numbers
def beginning_letter_check(b):
    # using list slicing
    if b[0:2].isalpha():
        return True
    else:
        return False

# function to check whether the plate number inputted contains any signs(punctuation marks, period, etc) or not
def sign_checker(s):
    # importing all types of punctuations
    punctuation = string.punctuation
    # looping through the plate number
    for i in s:
        # checking whether each of the value of the plate number is similar to the punctuation marks obtained as a string using the function above
        if i in punctuation:
            return False
    return True

# function to check that the plate number doesnot contain any digits in between the alphabets
def middle_number_checker(m):
    # assigning the value to a local variable
    middle_numbers = m

    # if the length of the plate number inputted is 6
    if len(m) == 6:
        if middle_numbers[2].isdigit() and middle_numbers[3].isdigit() and middle_numbers[4].isdigit() and middle_numbers[5].isdigit():
            return True
        elif middle_numbers[2].isdigit() and middle_numbers[3].isdigit() and middle_numbers[4].isdigit() and middle_numbers[5].isalpha():
            return False
        elif middle_numbers[2].isdigit() and middle_numbers[3].isalpha() and middle_numbers[4].isdigit():
            return False
        elif middle_numbers[2].isdigit() and middle_numbers[3].isalpha() and middle_numbers[4].isalpha():
            return False
        elif middle_numbers[2].isdigit() and middle_numbers[3].isdigit() and middle_numbers[4].isalpha() and middle_numbers[5].isdigit():
            return False
        elif middle_numbers[2].isdigit() and middle_numbers[3].isdigit() and middle_numbers[4].isalpha() and middle_numbers[5].isalpha():
            return True
        elif middle_numbers[2].isalpha() and middle_numbers[3].isalpha() and middle_numbers[4].isdigit() and middle_numbers[5].isdigit():
            return True
        elif middle_numbers[2].isalpha() and middle_numbers[3].isalpha() and middle_numbers[4].isdigit() and middle_numbers[5].isalpha():
            return False
        elif middle_numbers[2].isalpha() and middle_numbers[3].isdigit() and middle_numbers[4].isalpha():
            return False
        elif middle_numbers[2].isalpha() and middle_numbers[3].isdigit() and middle_numbers[4].isdigit() and middle_numbers[5].isalpha():
            return False
        elif middle_numbers[2].isalpha() and middle_numbers[3].isdigit() and middle_numbers[4].isdigit() and middle_numbers[5].isdigit():
            return True
        elif middle_numbers[2].isalpha() and middle_numbers[3].isalpha() and middle_numbers[4].isalpha() and middle_numbers[5].isalpha():
            return True

    # if the length of the plate number inputted is 5
    elif len(m) == 5:
        if middle_numbers[2].isdigit() and middle_numbers[3].isdigit() and middle_numbers[4].isdigit():
            return True
        elif middle_numbers[2].isdigit() and middle_numbers[3].isdigit() and middle_numbers[4].isalpha():
            return False
        elif middle_numbers[2].isdigit() and middle_numbers[3].isalpha() and middle_numbers[4].isdigit():
            return False
        elif middle_numbers[2].isdigit() and middle_numbers[3].isalpha() and middle_numbers[4].isalpha():
            return False
        elif middle_numbers[2].isalpha() and middle_numbers[3].isalpha() and middle_numbers[4].isdigit():
            return True
        elif middle_numbers[2].isalpha() and middle_numbers[3].isdigit() and middle_numbers[4].isalpha():
            return False
        elif middle_numbers[2].isalpha() and middle_numbers[3].isdigit() and middle_numbers[4].isdigit():
            return True
        elif middle_numbers[2].isalpha() and middle_numbers[3].isalpha() and middle_numbers[4].isalpha():
            return True

    # if the length of the plate number inputted is 4
    elif len(m) == 4:
        if middle_numbers[2].isdigit() and middle_numbers[3].isdigit():
            return True
        elif middle_numbers[2].isdigit() and middle_numbers[3].isalpha():
            return False
        elif middle_numbers[2].isalpha() and middle_numbers[3].isalpha():
            return True
        elif middle_numbers[2].isalpha() and middle_numbers[3].isdigit():
            return True

    # if the length of the plate number inputted is 3
    elif len(m) == 3:
        return True

    # if the length of the plate number inputted is 2
    else:
        return True


# function to check the whether the first number in the plate text inpitted contain is '0' or not as the first number in the number plate cannot be '0'
def zero_checker(z):
    # looping throught the plate number one at a time
    for i in z:
        # checking whether that particular number is '0' or not
        if i.isdigit():
            # if the number is '0', then returning false
            if i == "0":
                return False
            else:
                return True
    return True



main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I solved it

```
def main():
    plate = input("Plate: ")
    if is_valid(plate):
        print("Valid")
    else:
       print("Invalid")
    
def is_valid(s):
    # Check if alphanumeric and has 2-6 chars
    if s.isalnum() and 2 <= len(s) <= 6:

        # Outcome 1: Min. 2 alphabets followed by numbers
        # Check first 2 chars are alphabets and last char is digit
        if s[0].isalpha() and s[1].isalpha() and s[len(s) - 1].isdigit():
            position = 0
            while position < len(s) - 1:
                # Check if the first appearing digit is not 0
                if s[position] == "0":
                    return False
                # No letters in-between numbers
                if s[position].isdigit():
                    if s[position+1].isalpha():
                        return False
                position += 1
            return True
    
        # Outcome 2: All chars are alphabets
        # Check if all chars are letters
        elif s.isalpha():
            return True


main()
```

Comment: note your solution is wrong as there can be more than 2 letters to start a valid plate.

Answer (score 1):

Since the answers I saw were lacking I posted a more streamlined solution that only uses one pass.

```py
import string

def is_valid(plate):
  #check plate length
  if len(plate) < 2 or len(plate) > 6:
    return False

  #make sure there's at least two letters
  if not (plate[0].isalpha() and plate[1].isalpha()):
     return False

  #check from 2 till the end to make sure no leading 0 and no letters after alphas
  i = 0
  found_num = False
  for i < len(plate):
    if not found_num:
      if plate[i].isdigit():
        if plate[i] = '0': #no first 0
          return False
        else:
          found_num == True
      elif not plate[i].isalpha(): #bad character
        return False
    elif plate[i].isalpha(): #digit had a letter after
      return False
    i=i+1;
  return True
 
// MAIN
plate = input("Plate: ")
if is_valid(plate):
    print("Valid")
else:
    print("Invalid")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my answer. I have checked and should work, hopefully this is the answer to your problem. It is slightly messy and not clean.

```
def main():
    plate = input("Plate: ")
    if is_valid(plate):
        print("Valid")

else:
    print("Invalid")


def is_valid(s):
    x = len(s)
    if x < 2 or x > 6:
        return False
    else:
        x = s
        x = x[0:2]
        x = x.isalpha()
        if x == False:
            return False
    x = s
    length = len(s)
    length = length - 1
    length1 = length - 1
    a = 0
    for i in s:
        isalphabet = i.isalpha()
        isnumber = i.isdigit()
        if isnumber == True:
            i = int(i)
        final_character = x[length1 :length]
        final_character_isalpha = final_character.isalpha()
        while isnumber == True and a == 0:
            if isnumber == True and i == 0:
                a = a + 1
                return False
            elif isnumber == True:
                a = a + 1


    if final_character_isalpha == True and isnumber == True:
        return False

    if isalphabet == False and isnumber == False:
        return False



    return True




main()
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

```py
def main():
    plate = input("Plate: ").upper()
    if is_valid(plate):
        print("Valid")
    else:
        print("Invalid")


def is_valid(s):
    if not s.isalnum():
        return False

    if len(s) < 2 or len(s) > 6:
        return False

    L = list(s)

    if not L[0].isdigit() or not L[1].isdigit():
        return False

    for i in range(len(L) - 1):
        if L[i].isdigit():
            if not L[i + 1].isdigit():
                return False

    return True

main()
```

this is my solution(unfortunatelly half-working)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

```
def main():
    plate = input("Plate: ")
    print("Valid") if is_valid(plate) else print("Invalid")

def is_valid(s):
    if 1 < len(s) < 7 and s.isalnum():
        for c in s:
            if c.isdigit():
                if c == '0':
                    return False
                idx = s.index(c) 
                if s[0:idx] == '': # if the first char is digit return false
                    return False
                elif not s[idx: len(s)].isnumeric(): #if the 2nd half has at least one alpha char return false
                    return False
                else: # all good
                    return True
        return True # if the plate doesn't contain digits and satisfies character number limitations then just return true

main()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

```py
def main():
    plate = input("Plate: ")
    if is_valid(plate):
        print("Valid")
    else:
        print("Invalid")

def middle(s):
    if len(s) == 6 and s[2].isdigit() and not s[2:].isdigit():
        return False
    return True


def is_valid(s):
    return 2 <= len(s) <= 6 and s[0:2].isalpha() and s.isalnum() and s[2] != "0" and middle(s)


main()
```