# loop from a specific part

Tags: python, cs50

I want to check if all characters following the first digit in a string are also digits, and there are no alphabetic characters
Numbers cannot be used in the middle of a plate; they must come at the end. For example, AAA222 would be an acceptable … vanity plate; AAA22A would not be acceptable. The first number used cannot be a ‘0’.”

```
def main():
    user_input = input("Plate: ")
    is_val = valid_plate(user_input)
    if is_val:
        print("Valid")
    else:
        print("Invalid")


def valid_plate(plate):
    if len(plate) < 2 or len(plate) > 6:
        return False
    not_allowed = [" ", ",", "!", "."]
    for char in plate:
        if char in not_allowed:
            return False
    for char in plate:
        if char.isdigit():
           if char.startswith("0"):
              return False
        elif plate[-1:].isdigit():
              return True
        else:
        return False

    return True


main()
```

the problem am having is when i have something like wil20p2 it should be false not True
and but i get True because i slide from the end and check if it's a digit and it return True but it
need to be force because the 20 then go inside the middle
the rest work fine

Comment: Not sure if this is your problem, but you have a nested loop that I don't think you intended to do. you Have `for char in plate` nested.

Comment: @blackbrandt you right is because i copied and paste from my code and did not go through the indentation you are right

Answer (score 0):

Here is modified version of the code. You iterate over the plate characters using `zip()` - to get two characters each iteration. Then you check if the first character is number and second character not a number (if this condition is True, the check fails). Similar for the check if the number starts with zero.

```py
def check(plate):
    assert 2 <= len(plate) <= 6

    for c1, c2 in zip(plate, plate[1:]):
        # check if there isn't digit before character
        if c1.isdigit() and not c2.isdigit():
            return False

        # the digit begins with 0?
        if not c1.isdigit() and c2 == "0":
            return False

    return True


test_cases = ["wi20p2", "AAA222", "AAA22A", "AAA022", "AAA202"]

for t in test_cases:
    print(t, check(t))
```

Prints:

```
wi20p2 False
AAA222 True
AAA22A False
AAA022 False
AAA202 True
```

Comment: this is a dupe it has been asked a dozen times

Comment: @UpAndAdam Actually I've never seen this question before...seems like question for computer-class. I close this question then.

Comment: It's from the CS50 class, look at the tag.... and then search for CS50 vanity plates

Comment: here's another instance of it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73428241/cs50-vanity-plates-detecting-numbers-amid-letters?noredirect=1&lq=1